# Blazor - HTML dropdown element once activated stops any further @OnClick event triggers

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-server-side

Not sure if anyone has experienced this before but I have tried some solutions online but still can't manage to sort this. This is my situation:

I have create a simple app with a **Dropdown Test** button and a **Normal Test** button that once I click any on them I get the following outcome:

**Normal Test**

Once selected then the OnClick event triggers and just a simple console writeline stating the event was called gets actioned. This I can do over and over which is perfect.

**Dropdown Test**

Once selected then the OnClick event triggers and just a simple console writeline stating the event was called gets actioned. This I can only do once, thereafter it fails to call the OnClick event again which I need it to do.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnTest" type="button">Normal Test</button>
  <br />
  <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" @onclick="OnTest" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
     Dropdown Test
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">ValueA</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">ValueB</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">ValueC</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>

@code
{
private void OnTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PauseFeed called!");
    }
}
```

I need the dropdown button to run the OnClick event everytime I select the dropdown, not sure if there is a statechange event to run or how I would do this.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Give `onchange` a try.

Comment: Tried @onchange and although the dropdown works, this doesn't trigger the event. Unless I'm doing it wrong, even passed the ChangeEventArgs .

Comment: No issue with your code....

Comment: Can you try using <select onchange=...> instead?

Comment: <select onchange> does work as choosing the values does raise the event, unfortunately I need the dropdown menu hidden until the button is selected to provide the necessary options to the user. On the button selection I have a timer that would run in the background that will timeout after 15sec for the user to make a decision, should the decision not be made in that timeframe I need to do some other logic, but the point is that I can't start the timer afterwards anymore.

Comment: It's almost like once the onclick event triggers, that specific dropdown can't rerun the clicked event. I just tested by adding a separate dropdown and I can only trigger the onclick event once per dropdown, any ideas how to unclick the dropdown or reset the element so that it is in a refreshed state? Only way to currently get it working is to refresh the page which isn't ideal.

Comment: @Brakkie101.  I assuming this is Bootstrap and you have referenced Bootstrap JS files.  The dropdowns utilize *Popper.js*.  I haven't dug into the code (I'm no JS expert), but what I think is happening is Popper is interacting with the local DOM and breaking the Blazor client => Blazor Server DOM synchronisation.  Specifically the event management of the onclick event on the button.  Works first time, as Popper hasn't yet intervened.  You probably need to look at a different dropdown implementation.  I came across this problem ages ago and changed my design.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I had a feeling that something like this might be the case. I'm at this point already looking at an alternative so was hoping that someone might know of a way but if I get no fix or answer by end of day then I'll change design too. Thanks.

Comment: @Brakkie101 You might want to take a look at Blazorise if you are using Boostrap. It provides a wrapper for all Bootstrap items as Razor components. Maybe take a look [here](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/dropdown/).

Comment: Also just seen this when looking for something else https://blazorstrap.io/buttongroups

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the feedback received.

I had a look at the options provided and have decided to rather just change the design.

Thanks.